# rails: what is the most efficient way to store sessions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I am implementing a dynamic application for 4 desktops in my house so i don't think that security is big issue however i would like to know what is the most efficient wayto implement sessions?cookies ?store it in the database or in the memory?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the use-case you describe I see no reason not to use the Rails' default of cookie-based session storage.

Answer (score 1):

Security is no issue...then cookies should be the best.